# how to get the id of a tr inside the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i got the tr content like this way simil

```js
 var td = $("tr td"); // get first child of all the td elements
        var htmlContent = []; // initilize an empty array
        for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
            htmlContent[i] = $(td[i]).text();
           trid[i] = $(td[i]).attr("id");
           
        }
```

i want the tr id so i use this code

> ```
> trid[i] = $(td[i]).attr("id");
> ```
>
> but this is not good

Comment: `var td = $("tr td"); // get first child of all the td elements`. No, it's not. It returns all `td` which are located within `tr` (i.e., all).

Comment: id of TR or id of TD? please clarify.

Comment: Please post your HTML to clarify all of us.

Comment: make a fiddle instead it will help others to resolve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **.parent()** to get the tr, and then its id.

```
var htmlContent = []; // initilize an empty array
$('tr td').each(function () {
    htmlContent.push($(this).text());
     console.log($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

Here is a simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hxsbLws2/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `td` only since it is already a DOM object. You don't need to use it as a selector again like this `$(td)` ..

Then just specify the index `td[i]`

`trid[i] = td[i].attr('id');`